# Adding vertical distance between subfigure environments

Tags: graphics, subfloats, subcaption

When having subfigures not only horizontally but also vertically in a `figure`-environment, their subcaptions are placed very close to the below subfigure. Essentially because the `subfigure`-environments are placed tightly close vertically. The arrow points where I would like more vertical space:

[image]

How can this be achieved? A working test latex code is this ([ShareLatex demo here](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/58e4e28a54b8ca05149425b0)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{placeholder.jpg}
      \caption{Picture 1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{0.25cm}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{placeholder.jpg}
      \caption{Picture 2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{placeholder.jpg}
      \caption{Picture 3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{0.25cm}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{placeholder.jpg}
      \caption{Picture 4}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Pictures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add something like `\vspace{3ex}` just after the second subfigure. Other possibility: use the `subfloatrow` environment (from package `floatrow`).

Comment: @Bernard `\vspace` does not seem to make any difference

Comment: With the code you posted?

Comment: @Steeven Try `\\[3ex]` instead.

Comment: @Troy Thank you, this works. Yes, Bernard, I added it to the linked demo.

Comment: @Troy I think your comment deserve to be answer. Just saw it by chance ans solved a similar issue of mine.

Answer (score 2):

Try `\\[3ex]` between subfigures, adjusting the size to taste.